# How to automatically predict the opinion of a person for a movie

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, svm

I want to automatically predict the opinion of a person for a movie.

My method.
I gather all the reviews for each movie. I did this for 30200 movies.
I gathered 20 features for all the 30200 movies (income variable).
I did a user study. In my user study I asked ten questions (outcome variable) to people who watched the movie. 900 users participated in my study and scored 200 movies (on average 5 scores per movie).
Based on the experience that I gathered threw the user study I want to predict the opinions of the user for the other 30000 movies. How can I do this?
I have experience with machine learning in python(also in R). But with machine learning I am only able to automatically predict one opinion question but not all the 10 opinions.

To make it clear I am describing my dataset:
Input:
X=scores that I gathered based on reviews.
I have 20 variables with scores from 0 till 10.

Target/Output(/What I want to predict):
Y=answer set of questions of a user for a movie
I have 10 questions. (y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10)
The scores are scaled 1 till 5.

Based on X I am able to predict y1 or y2 (not both together).
But I want to to automatically predict this for all (y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10).
I am only able to do this with Bayesian automatically (which is undesirable) but not with knn or svm. Do you guys know how I could perform this prediction in for all the Y values automatically?
(Not by changing y1 to y2)

How would you guys handle this case? Is machine learning the right tool and/or are there other tools then can help me in my case?